# Как выводить пиксели на экран или окна?

Tags: qt, графика, gtk

Нужно выводить пиксели на экран или окна своей графической библиотекой. Без использования `XWindow GTK Qt`.

Например `Xwindow GTK Qt` как то выводят на экран свои окна. Как они это делают? Наверное выводят по-пиксельно, но как?

Comment: Имею ввиду что я сам хочу без qt gtk xwindow выводить окна на экран. Своя графическая библиотека.

Comment: Через графические примитивы, то есть наборы изображений. Например, окно разбивается на набор элементов - углы, отрезки горизонтальных и вертикальных линий, а потом, при создании окна все это компонуется вместе. По современному можно и css прикрутить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GTK и Qt имеют доступ к графике через XWindow, иначе никак, вы что хотите получить в защищённой системе доступ к аппаратуре? В общем самый нижний уровень к которому вы можете получить доступ в *nix это протокол X11. В windows это GDI.

Другой вариант, не самый лёгкий писать свою операционную систему или хотя бы ядро.

Comment: А средствами opengl можно выводить? Как?

Comment: но opengl ведь тоже на голом железе imho не бывает. Если не секрет, где это должно работать?

Comment: В линуксе. Но я видел в kde что можно выставить режим отрисовки в opengl, или это не то.

Comment: Да это конечно можно, тогда изучайте opengl, мобильный Qt по моему полностью базируется на opengl, opengl - это по сути стандартизированный интерфейс к видеоускорителю

Comment: Но как начать? Как доступ к поверхности получить если с opengl писать?

Comment: ну всё в примерах есть, там всё на списках, создал список точек или линий и отправляешь его по открытому заранее контексту

Comment: на linux можно обойтись и без X11, например работать в виртуальной консоли с фреймбуфером или работать с графикой через dri, но в обоих случаях, если ты не собираешься писать замену X11 — это особое древнее/современное извращение.